# Time from the block added to the pool to time it gets executed

Tags: monerod, daemon, monero-wallet-rpc, blockchain-data

Is there a way to get the data for when each block has been added to the pool and to when it has been executed in monero?

Comment: What do you mean by "when it has been executed in monero?" ?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, blocks don't get "added to the pool". A wallet instructs a daemon to broadcast a transaction which gets added to the transaction pool. A miner constructs a block template by bunching transactions that are in the transaction pool, then mining that block template. When a miner successfully mines a block, it is broadcast to the network, and if valid, get's added to each peers blockchain.

If you need an external notification when your node adds a block to your blockchain, you can use the parameter `--block-notify` when starting your node, which will instruct it to execute a program every time a block is added:

```
monerod --help
  ...
  --block-notify arg                    Run a program for each new block, '%s' 
                                        will be replaced by the block hash
  ...
```

You can also call the daemon's RPC method [get_last_block_header](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_last_block_header), which includes a timestamp field in the response. Note that this timestamp however is a miner created timestamp, not the time your node added the block to your local blockchain.

Comment: can we get the information for the current blocks on the chain.. when they were added to transaction pool and when they were added to the chain?

Comment: Again, blocks are not added to the tx pool. You can get the time a block was added to the chain by calling [get_last_block_header](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_last_block_header), which includes a timestamp in the response.

Comment: Transactions, not blocks, are added to the txpool. A block may include transactions that were added to the txpool at different times.